# PHP RegEx to Extract Phone No

Tags: php, regex, email, extract, phone-number

```
bid=
id=3D46799862
03005134012
 +92-345-540700(8)
(00996)-345.(123)/4567 
 bidid=3D46799862). +966 235 123456/7
    * Need to make a payment?  You can do it here (https://www.elance.com/p=+92 123 4567891
hp/project/main/projectInvoices.php?bidid=3D46799862).
    /receivingpmbmessages.html).
<a href=3D"http://help.elance.com/entries/20992337-valign=3D"bottom" style=3D"font-s=
ize:10px; color:#817f80;padding:0px;margin:0px;">1-877-435-2623 | Mon-Fri 8=
```

Testing at http://rubular.com/r/U0YZQ0GlbZ
RegEx `(\d|\+)(\+|\d|\(|\)|-| |\.){7,}\b`
Expected matches :

1. 03005134012
2. +92-345-540700(8)
3. (00996)-345.(123)/4567
4. +966 235 123456/7
5. +92 123 4567891
6. 1-877-435-2623

incorrect matches :

1. matching `46799862` but should be ignore beacause complete word is `3D46799862`
2. matching `+92-345-540700(8` and it should match `+92-345-540700(8)`
3. matching `00996)-345.(123` but it should match `(00996)-345.(123)/4567`
4. matching `46799862). +966 235 123456` but it should match `+966 235 123456/7`
5. Matching `20992337-` but it should be ignored because its `/20992337-valign=`

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Dunno if it's of help, but [Elance have an API](https://www.elance.com/q/api2). Can you get what you need in a more robust way through that?

Comment: my question is simple, i need to extract correct matches but my regular expression is incorrect. how it should be

Comment: you answer is awsume, i have a question in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\d|\+|\()(\+|\d|\(|\)|-| |\/){7,}(\d|\))+\b
```

This is more accurate...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you wan't a regular expression that only matches the 6 expected matches.

This regular expression does that.

```
(?<!(?:\w|\/))(?:\d|\+|\()[\d ()\/\.-]+(?!\w)
```

It has to start with either a \d, + or (. But only if there is no preceding \w or /.

Then just consume one or more of [\d ()/.-] but not if it ends with a \w

**EDIT**

`(?<...)` is a negative lookbehind. In this case it means that the previous charaters cannot match the regex `...`

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. So like above it means that the next characters cannot match the regex `...`

Both of the above contructs is non-consuming.

`(?:...)` is a non capturing group

Comment: can you please explain your regular expression. i don't what is "<" and "!" and ":" and "?!"

Comment: Google regex and lookahead/lookbehind it is non consuming assertions