# detecting phone number format in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have about 10 thousand strings that I want to extract phone numbers from, some of the phone number format is the following:

```
08978803929
085282486601
081284671191
+6285722345678
```

The pattern is as follows, it's either a consecutive string of numbers starting with 08, it can either be 11 digit or 12 digit. It can also have an area code of +62 in front of it. How do I extract all of these string using a regular expression in PHP?

To make it even more simpler, I want to detect strings that starts with 08 or +62 or just 62

Comment: just saying, that a `+` character may be replaced by a `00` in phone numbers. Is this true for you too?

Comment: @STTLCU no that is not true

Comment: This will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849158/php-regex-to-extract-phone-no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(\+?62|08)[0-9]{9,11}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
- ^ and $    - Line start and Line end
- (\+?62|08) - starting with 62 OR +61 OR 08
[0-9]{9,11}  - match 9 to 11 digits
```

Comment: what does the {9,11} means at the end?

Comment: @adit min. 9 and max. 11, or also between 9 and 11 occurances ;-)

Comment: Its length of the string starting from 0.

Comment: @adit: Added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @anubhava I tried the following an it gives me an error? $matches = array();
      preg_match('^(\+?62|08)[0-9]{9,11}$', $string, $matches);

Comment: @adit: Made a demo for you: http://ideone.com/q1UjMd

Comment: @anubhava actually this doesn't work with this string '+6285722345678 anjing' or if the phone number is in the middle or the end? It has to work for the following string as well 'hello my name is X and +6285722345678 and then....'

Comment: @adit: In that case use this regex: `\b(\+?62|08)[0-9]{9,11}\b`

Comment: so like this @anubhava preg_match('\b(\+?62|08)[0-9]{9,11}\b', $shop->getBio(), $matches)

Comment: @anubhava that gives me an error of 'Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in'

Comment: It should be: **`preg_match('/\b(\+?62|08)[0-9]{9,11}\b/', $shop->getBio(), $matches);`**